# Akka: getContext().parent vs getSender() for response sending

Tags: akka, response, actor

I started using Akka in my project in order to introduce parallelization and enhance the performance of my application.

In this regard, I have a question related to the use of the `getContext.parent()` method versus the `GetSender()` method, when one needs to send a message back to an actor who is both the parent of the current actor, and the sender of the currently-handled message.

**Context of the question**

My program creates a system with a `Report` actor, and child `Page` actors.

I have my `Report` actor asking each page to perform various treatments with a `getToWork` message, and the `Page` sends back a `jobFinished` message to the `Report` actor, so that it knows every page is done.

**Questions**

Which, between `getContext().parent().tell` (using `ActorRef.noSender()` for the `getToWork` message) and `getSender().tell()` (using `getSelf()` for the `getToWork` message):

- Is the fastest?
- Is the most memory-efficient?
- Is the least prone to errors?

Considering that I work on a Big Data project, which will have to treat as many objects as quickly as possible, these questions interests me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any big differences in efficiency between the alternatives. Sending to the sender might make your actors a little easier to test and/or refactor.